# How to select the nth html element in a table that has special class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch.js to test a website. On this website there is a table which looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="sorting_1">...</td>
    <td class="sorting_2">...</td>
    <td class="sorting_3">...</td>
    <td class="sorting_3">...</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to check if this table contains the correct words. I found out that it is possible to select an element this way:

```
'td[class="sorting_2"]'
```

I can get the text with this command:

```
.getText('td[class="sorting_2"]', function(result){
    this.assert.equal(result.value, 'Testbenutzer');
})
```

But what do I have to do if I want to select one of two equally defined elements like in the list above. The last two elements both have the class `sorting_3`. How can I get the nth element of the table with a special class.
I already tried this:

```
'td:nth-of-type(1)[class="sorting_3"]'
'td:nth-child(1)[class="sorting_3"]'
'td[class="sorting_3"]:nth-child(1)'
'td:nth-child(3)'
```

Nothing of this worked. How can I do it?

Comment: How do you know which item to select? Is it an idea to loop through all elements that have the class?

Comment: I think you definitely need to specify an unique attribute like <td column-index="4" like that

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`?

Comment: `'td.sorting_3:nth-child(1)'` gives this error: `ERROR: Unable to locate element: "td.sorting_3:nth-child(1)" using: css selector
`

Comment: What do you get inside the callback when you use `'td.sorting_3'`? If it's an array or DomNodeList you can iterate that.

Comment: i am not using jquery, i also cannot change the source code.

Comment: `'td.sorting_3'` only gives me the first element.

Comment: `td[class="sorting_3"]` gives you the first of element out of all `.sorting_3` elements?

Comment: If nightwatch uses CSS selectors, this should work:
td.sorting_3:nth-child(1) or even just: .sorting_3:nth-child(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of accessing multiple `.sorting_3` elements, without knowledge of how `Nightwatch.js` actually works, is to pass it *siblings* `~` combinator selector.

i.e.: when you want to select the first element out of `.sorting_3` elements, you would do this:

```
.getText('td[class="sorting_3"]', function(result){
    this.assert.equal(result.value, 'Testbenutzer');
})
```

And for second element:

```
.getText('td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"]', function(result){
    this.assert.equal(result.value, 'Testbenutzer');
})
```

And so on ...

Problem is, this approach is not scalable. You will need to know ahead of time how many elements are you expecting in the `.sorting_3` selector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it helped. While I am at it, you could also shorten the selectors by using `$` symbol to select class names ending at `_3`. So your selector would become `td[class$="_3"]`. I think this is a nice feature to know too wouldn't you agree?

Comment: i tried this for a mac address input, but it only works for the first three elements. is there a limit?

Comment: as I mentioned, this approach doesn't *scale* well. Tell me more about what you are trying to do now? May be we can find a way to solve it too.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i noticed that i don't need to access every single field explicitly

Comment: We are still talking about Nightwatch.js right? Since it is built on top of Selenium, there must be a way to directly call & utilise Selenium API. I believe Selenium exposes handful of very useful methods: [[Link](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#protocol)].

Comment: now i face a similar problem again. i have a table and want to get the 6th column of the thead tag. How can i do this?

Comment: can't you form the selector in similar way like: `'td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"] ~ td[class="sorting_3"]'`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `[<n>]` notation to select the first, or second, etc.

```
//td[@class="sorting_3"][1]
//td[@class="sorting_3"][2]
```

The values of `1` and `2` correspond to the first and second, respectively.

```js
function find_nodes(selector, callback)
{
  var result = document.evaluate(selector, document);

  var node = result.iterateNext();
  while (node) {
    callback(node);
    node = result.iterateNext();
  }
}

find_nodes('//td[@class="sorting_3"][1]', function(node) {
  node.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
});

find_nodes('//td[@class="sorting_3"][2]', function(node) {
  node.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="sorting_1">foo</td>
    <td class="sorting_2">bar</td>
    <td class="sorting_3">baz</td>
    <td class="sorting_3">qux</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately this leads to an error message. this seems not to be supported by nightwatch.js

Comment: @Garrarufa what's the error message? if it supports xpath selectors, it should be able to handle this.

Comment: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @Garrarufa I didn't even mention `document` in my answer; the code snippet is just there to demonstrate it works in a browser that supports it. The important part is the selector path itself.

Comment: ok, but when i use the selector it gives me this error message: `ERROR: Unable to locate element: "td[class="sorting_3"][2]" using: css selector
`

Comment: @Garrarufa Hmm, could you try with `//td` instead?

Comment: this is the same: `ERROR: Unable to locate element: "//td[class="sorting_3"][2]" using: css selector
`

Comment: @Garrarufa Perhaps you should check [this thread](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/33) out regarding XPath selector support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution that `Jack` proposed(`//td[@class="sorting_3"][1]`), but you have to set Nightwatch to use xPath as the locateStrategy.  From the errors you were getting, your default locateStrategy appears to be `CSS`.  See [this command in the API reference](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#useXpath)